# Ajax request not being performed after validation passes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am trying to use ajax to validate user credentials after i have validated the user has input data into the required fields but the ajax request is not being performed at all. I don't know what is causing all but i will really appreciate any clues and answers given. Here is my code

```
/*global $*/
/*global _*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#login-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        var form_items = {
            username: { required: true, name: 'Username' },
            password: { required: true, name: 'Password' },
            token: {}
        };


        var $login_form = $(this);
        var submit_form = false;

        var validation = new Validation( form_items );
        validation = validation.check( $login_form['context'] );

        // if the error list display is there, remove it
        $('.bg-danger').parent().remove();
        // If any element has the class for errors, remove the class
        $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');

        if ( validation.passed() ) {
            var data = validation.getData();
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "ajax/login.ajax.php",
                data: data
            }).done(function ( response ) {
                console.log( response );
            });
        } else {
            var errors = validation.getErrors();
            var display = '<div class="form-group"><ul class="bg-danger">';
            _.each( errors, function(elem, index, list) {
                var $form_element = $('#'+index); // get form element
                $form_element.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
                display += '<li>' + elem + '</li>';
            });
            display += '</ul></div>';
            $login_form.prepend( display );
        }

        if ( !submit_form ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

And here is screenshot of my console after validation has passed
[image]

Comment: The problem is that your ajax request isn't executed at all? Have you looked inside validation.passed() with console.log() if it is sometimes true? Maybe add .error to you ajax request to see if an error happened during the request.

Comment: @Schlumpf I have done all that and everything seems to work fine, is there anything more i can do

Comment: Have ever looked inside your Browser Developer Tool Console (Mostly F12)? An Ajax Request can be seen there. So you should see if the request failed or suceeded. If your problem is that the ajax request will be never maid then tell that again? It is not clear at all what's exactly your problem! Does the ajax request fail or will that code never be reached? Give a more detailed answer

Comment: As per screenshot of console, what is that object? username, password and token? is that `console.log(response)` result?